# Animating width to a specified percent and showing the percent from 0 to that specified percent while animating

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want `bar` to get animated from `width:0` to `width:95%`.

Also I want the percentage to be shown from `0%` to `95%` inside `.barPercent` element while `width` is animated.

But with what i tried, the width animation ends whereas percentages in `.barPercent` element have not reached to `95%` and stills is increased.

I can not find a way for them to match together and width animation and percentage increment done in the same time.

```js
 var bar = $('.bar'),
 percent = bar.find('.barPercent'),
 i=1, interval;
 percent.text(i + '%');
 i++;
 interval = setInterval(function(){
 percent.text(i + '%');
 if(i == 95){
  clearInterval(interval);
 }
 i++;
 },2000/95);
 bar.animate({
 width: 95 + '%'
  },2000,'linear');
```

```css
 .bar{
      height: 30px;
      background: red;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .barPercent {
     width: 50px;
     height: 40px;
     position: absolute;
     top: -5px;
     right: 0;
     background: #81858a;
     line-height: 40px;
     text-align: center;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 0.88em;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="barContainer">
  <div>HTML</div>
   <div class="bar" data-width="95">
    <span class="barPercent">0</span>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to make `width` and `percentages increment` to be done in the same time?

Is there a better solution?

Why don't their duration match?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to match the total animation duration to be same for all 3? That seems to be happening now. If you want them to have same length, then total duration will have to be different based on their final length

Comment: @Alwaysa Learner No I want animating width and increasing percentage be the same for every bar. Like animating width for first one from 0 to 95% of its parent's width and showing percentage for it from 0% to 95% be done in 2000ms.

Comment: In that case total duration of each bar will be different. Try this > Change the interval values as shown in the answer below... now bars will grow together and stop when their respective max width is reached. Your code was all good, but I think you got confused between 2 operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.bar').each(function () {

    duration = 2000; //in ms
    step = 0.5; //increase in width in px

    var bar = $(this),
        percent = bar.find('.barPercent'),
        barWidth = Number(bar.data('width')),
        i = 1,
        interval;
/*
    percent.text(i + '%');
    i++;*/

    interval = setInterval(function () {
        widthNumb = Math.floor(i);
        percent.text(widthNumb + '%');
        if (i >= barWidth) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        bar.css({
            "width": i + '%'
        });

        i = i + step;
    }, Math.floor(duration / barWidth / 10));

    /*
    bar.animate({
        width: barWidth + '%'
    }, duration/step, 'linear'); //
    */
});
```

I used a step variable = 0.5 to increase the width in px, however the % text shown will be in whole numbers using Math.floor. You can play arund by changing the values of duration and step

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering, sorry i think my question was not clear enough. This is not what i wanted. I edited my question please see

Comment: Strange, but I did not face this issue when I tried this code on Chrome. Both number % and bar width stopped at the exact same time on all 3 bars.

Comment: This is intriguing :) Only thing  I can think of is that Firefox is taking longer to process what's inside interval function....  and the solution would be to increase the bar width by directly changing the value inside interval function instead of carrying out a separate animate function. check my edited answer.